# Convert yyyyMMddhhmmss to datetime in dax(SSAS)

Tags: business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

We want to convert a yyyyMMddhhmmss column to datetime format in SSAS.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I used.
I hope it will be useful for you too.

```
=format(DATE(LEFT([datetimekey],4),MID([datetimekey],5,2),MID([datetimekey],7,2))+TIME(MID([datetimekey],9,2),MID([datetimekey],11,2),MID([datetimekey],13,2)),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
```